# UICollectionView cells disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

## Setup

I'm using the following to display a list of items.

1. UICollectionViewController
2. UICollectionViewFlowLayout

where:

> self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, kHeight);

So I'm essentially mimicking a table view (and giving myself the flexibility of using a different layout in the future).

I'm also using a UITabBarController, so I'm able to have different tabs.

### The Problem

When I switch very quickly back and forth to different tabs, sometimes the UICollectionView gets in the state where nothing appears.

Interestingly

> self.collectionView.visibleCells.count

returns 0.

As a solution, I tried doing this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [self.collectionView reloadData];
  [self.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem? And ideas for a solution?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @JPN I'm having the same problem. Did you find out why the UICollectionView disappears when switching tabs?

Comment: I did get this to work, but honestly, I don't remember how exactly. I basically just cleaned up my code, and refactored some of my thread 'hacks'.